# How can I float dynamic div's next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my own version of Twitter Bootstrap radio buttons purely based on CSS. The visual feedback for selected radio button is based on `input[type="radio"]:checked + span`.

As the content of my "buttons" can vary, the width is dynamic. This causes problem aligning the button next to each other.

In my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56f4C/2/) I've set fixed width of 50px. Removing this and the buttons are on top of each other.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
//HTML
<div class="button-group binary" data-toggle="buttons-radio"> 
    <div class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" class="active" name="status" value="1" />
        <span class="background">Yes</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="radio-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" class="inactive" name="status" value="0" checked="checked" />
        <span class="background">No</span>
    </div>
</div>

//CSS
.button-group{
    /*display: table;*/
    display: block;
}
.radio-wrapper {
    /*display: table-cell; */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 50px; /* I want this to be dynamic */
}

.radio-wrapper:first-child .background{
    border-right: 0;    
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.radio-wrapper:last-child .background{ 
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}


input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;   
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
     background-color: #63B1DE;
     color: #fff;
}


.background {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: solid 1px #87A2B2;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove `position: absolute` from you background class, you will no longer need the width style:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56f4C/3/)

```
.button-group{
    /*display: table;*/
    display: block;
}
.radio-wrapper {
    /*display: table-cell; */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    /*width: 50px;  not needed*/
}

.radio-wrapper:first-child .background{
    border-right: 0;    
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.radio-wrapper:last-child .background{ 
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}


input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;   
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
     background-color: #63B1DE;
     color: #fff;
}


.background {
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: solid 1px #87A2B2;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Dude, you made it seem so obvious! Now you got a gap between the buttons, but that is fixed by using table / table cell. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your CSS, I think the issue you are having is because you are making the `.background` `position: absolute` it is not taking up any space in its parent, so the parent doesn't really have any width, this is why you have to manually set it. Stripping out the absolute positioning for the `.background` and actually making it an element that takes up space will give the parent a width (which will be based on its content). Now as far as correcting the *on top of each other* issue, I would think some floating here would work. CSS is here (I also removed some unnecessary rules)

```
.radio-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
}

.radio-wrapper:first-child .background{
    border-right: 0;    
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.radio-wrapper:last-child .background{ 
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}


input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;   
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
     background-color: #63B1DE;
     color: #fff;
}


.background {   
    height: 100%;
    padding: .5em;
    border: solid 1px #87A2B2;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

As per example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLprU/1/).

I did add a bit more padding that you had though so please feel free to adjust as required. I also like padding in `ems` so if your font changes in size the padding is always relative.